# Error of make /usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -luvic

Tags: php, pdo, debian, ld

So im trying to "make" the source of my php FOLDER . @Debian

The difference with the default one is that ive configured pdo_u2 driver in it .

I am getting '/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -luvic '

I've installed lib-dev

Thanks for helping !

Comment: ive fixed it, i had to install libuvic.so inside /usr/lib .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the location where `luvic` lives is mentioned in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig`. Alternatively you can give the search path with `-Lpath`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, any idea of what "luvic" is ? aint finding anything about it